# Why is the "4" missing, even in the PDF?

Tags: math-mode, align, brackets

On the second line, marked by the beginning of the bracket, there should be a '4'. However, it doesn't show up, not even in the PDF.

[image]

Here is the code: (I am using ShareLaTeX, but the Compiler setting is XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Beispiel 4.2.3.1:}\\

 \begin{align*}
     A &= \begin{pmatrix*} 1 & 2 & 3 & 7\\0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix*} \; , \; B=\begin{pmatrix*} 4 & 1\\1 & 1\\ 0 & -2\\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix*}\\
     AB &= (2 \times \underbracket[0.6pt]{\mkern 4)\cdot(4 \mkern} \times 2) = (2 \times 2)\\
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `4` gets “eaten up” as the argument to the `\mkern` command.  **Edit:** BTW, you shold be getting an error “Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)”.

Comment: so i delete the first \mkern?

Comment: As they are written, both `\mkern` command are wrong.  Why are you using `\mkern` in the first place?

Comment: well i once had a question about something else and someone was using this and so i remembered how he used \underbracket

Comment: i didnt know i dont need these

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch In case this question is related to your cheat sheet, you might want to see Falk's scheme http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/ or Sarrus' scheme http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/mnemonic-rule-for-matrix-determinant/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to obtain that `\underbracket` doesn't add spacing  in  the multiplications, and you want some negative math kerning. Here's how to do it. You'll probably have to make some adjustments.

B.t.w., the `unicode-math` package should be loaded *after* all other math- and font-related packages — including the `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % load *after* all other math- and font-related packages

\begin{document}

\textbf{Beispiel 4.2.3.1:} 

\begin{align*}
     A &= \begin{pmatrix*} 1 & 2 & 3 & 7\\0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix*} \; , \; B=\begin{pmatrix*} 4 & 1\\1 & 1\\ 0 & -2\\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix*}\\
     AB &= (2 \times \underbracket[0.6pt]{\mkern -1mu 4)\cdot(4 \mkern -1mu}{} \times 2) = (2 \times 2)\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: as asked in the comments, here is a code for a coloured underbracket. I took the opportunity to improve the kerning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}


\textbf{Beispiel 4.2.3.1:}\\

 \begin{align*}
     A &= \begin{pmatrix*} 1 & 2 & 3 & 7\\0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix*} \; , \; B=\begin{pmatrix*} 4 & 1\\1 & 1\\ 0 & -2\\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix*}\\
     AB &= (2 \times \mkern 1.6mu\textcolor{IndianRed}{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\color{black}\mkern -1mu 4) \cdot (4 \mkern -1mu}}\mkern 1.4mu \times 2) = (2 \times 2)\\
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the information. Actually, I never tried to use unicode-math; so I had error messages about already defined symbols, and I though it was  of no use to load `amssymb`. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Welcome to the brave new world of unicode-based math and text document creation! :-)

Comment: @Bernad : how to get a red underbracket? I've tried {\red{\underbracket{}}} but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @pzorba75: I've posted a solution. Is it like you want?