# \xmapsto shows a "7" at the beginning of the arrow

Tags: math-mode, xetex, arrows, unicode-math

I am using XeTeX and need a text above the \mapsto arrow. So I googled for it and found the command for it. But unfortunately, this comes out:

[image]

So here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  F:\;\mathbb{K}^n \xmapsto{A} \mathbb{K}^m
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: okay wait ill edit

Comment: Don't use `fontenc` with XeTeX or LuaTeX. (That does not solve your issue here, but you should still not do load `fontenc`.)

Comment: Although I use text in the document? I am writing my math lectures in one document and there are explanations. But thank you for the tip

Comment: Your code causes many errors for me: `unicode-math` should probably be loaded after `amssymb`. `xmapsto` is a `mathtools` command, so that package should be loaded. (In the MWE even `align` is undefined because you did not load `mathtools` or `amsmath`...)

Comment: `fontenc` has nothing to with whether or not you write text or only formulae. It is about the engine you use. If you use pdf(La)TeX `fontenc` is a good idea, with Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX not so much.

Comment: well i am in sharelatex, but at a certain point i changed the compiler to XeTeX. Okay wait i just load all my packages i have

Comment: Given that you're using XeLaTeX, why are you loading the `times` and `lmodern` packages?

Comment: Like I said, I didnt use it in the beginning. I used the default Compiler of ShareLaTeX. And at certain points I needed those packages. But then after 50 pages I needed to change the PDF Compiler to the XeTeX compiler. Since I am using LaTeX since April, I am not such a pro and know which packages work in XeTeX or not. I just left these packages in and that didnt give me errors, believe me or not. But well, I would apreciate an answer why \xmapsto doesnt work properly here

Comment: You probably don't get to see some of the errors because ShareLaTeX soldiers on regardless and they have no discernible impact on typesetting. But that does not mean that you should not fix those errors. An example that makes it easier for people to help you would be as short as possible: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 F:\;\mathbb{K}^n \xmapsto{A} \mathbb{K}^m
\end{align*}
\end{document}`

Comment: You can find something about your problem at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/197 but as far as I can tell there is no fix for XeLaTeX yet.

Comment: yeah i found that too, but the code that they are posting to make the command doesnt change anything :< but thank you

Comment: Mhhh, question is: Do you really need `unicode-math` (it is a cool package, but it has some rough edges at times if you use many other established math packages) and XeLaTeX?

Comment: ah nevermind, it just worked :D

Comment: Really? It doesn't work for me. Please post an answer if you got this to work. BTW: I just noticed that you already got an answer that suggested to load `unicode-math` *after* `amssymb` and other math-related packages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434645/35864). You should definitely consider following the advice you get in answers.

Comment: yes i really need XeLaTeX, because I once wanted to do something (i forgot what, my document has 136 pages now) and it just works with XeLaTeX

Comment: \DeclareSymbolFont{pazosymbols}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn %define \xmapsto
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_minus \mathbin { pazosymbols } \c_zero
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_mapstochar \mathrel { pazosymbols } { "37 }
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_rightarrow \mathrel { pazosymbols } { "21 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pazo_relbar: {
  \mathrel {
    \mathpalette \mathsm@sh \c_pazo_minus
  }
}
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \MT_mapsto_fill: {
  \arrowfill@ { \c_pazo_mapstochar \pazo_relbar: } \pazo_relbar: \c_pazo_rightarrow
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

Comment: this worked out for me.

Answer (score 3):

So this worked out for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\DeclareSymbolFont{pazosymbols}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn %define \xmapsto
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_minus \mathbin { pazosymbols } 0
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_mapstochar \mathrel { pazosymbols } { "37 }
\DeclareMathSymbol \c_pazo_rightarrow \mathrel { pazosymbols } { "21 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pazo_relbar: {
  \mathrel {
    \mathpalette \mathsm@sh \c_pazo_minus
  }
}
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \MT_mapsto_fill: {
  \arrowfill@ { \c_pazo_mapstochar \pazo_relbar: } \pazo_relbar: \c_pazo_rightarrow
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  F:\;\mathbb{K}^n \xmapsto{A} \mathbb{K}^m
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\xmapsto}[2][]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\xmapsto@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\xmapsto@}[2]{\xmapsto@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\xmapsto@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mathop{}\limits_{\;#2\;}^{\;#3\;}$}%
  \mathop{\Uhextensible width \wd\z@ 0 "27FC}_{#2}^{#3}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
F\colon\mathbb{K}^n \xmapsto{A} \mathbb{K}^m \\
A \xmapsto[aaaaa]{bbbbbbbbbb} B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `\mapsto` is normally used not to denote a map with domain and codomain, but its action on elements.